# Adjust AutoSuggestBox SuggestionPane length

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am using an `AutoSuggestBox` bound to some objects. On mobiles, when the keyboard is open, the `AutoSuggestBox`'s `SuggestionPane` does not completely remain above the keyboard like this: [image: picture]

There's one more item inside the `SuggestionPane` that is hidden behind the keyboard. Now if I hide the software/virtual navigation button, it gets fixed like [image: this]

but if I keep these navigation buttons hidden and again tap the `AutoSuggestBox` to open up the `SuggestionPane` and the keyboard, the last item again goes behind the keyboard.

I always want all the items in `SuggestionPane` to be above the keyboard.

What I mean is that the when the keyboard is open, the keyboard can be in the front and the SuggestionPane can be behind the keyboard, but when I scroll down to the end, I should be able to see the last item ( should not be covered by keyboard )

I know there is a property of `AutoSuggestBox` to set the `MaxHeight` for a `SuggestionPane` but I cant figure out how to use it in this scenario.

And all these things are inside a `ContentDialog` ( if that matters)

Comment: You can try to only do that on mobile client.

Comment: again won't that be diferent for all mobile device

Comment: You are suggesting to decease the height of the pane so that it appears above the keyboard. But wont the height of keyboard differ in different mobiles ? Can I somehow use the MaxHeight property along with  `InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing` to get the `occludedRect` to change it dynamically ?

Comment: You can try calculating the height of the keyboard and do it dynamically.